# ¿Cómo ordernar elementos dentro de un div?

Tags: html, css

Estoy realizando una tabla, pero dentro de esta muestra diferentes resultados, en mi caso varias tablas dependiendo de cada habitacion, pero no se como hacer para que se muestre ordenadamente sin desordernarse, aqui les muestro como esta ahorita:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el contenedor es decir el que tiene los bordes rojo ocupa todo el ancho cuando son mas de 4 tablas dentro y se extiende y se desordena pues, alguna forma para que se mantenga ordenado? lo que quiero es algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que tome el ancho y la altura necesaria sin dejar ese espacion en blanco, aqui les dejo el codigo html:

```
<section class = "see_actual_products_section">
            <div id="products">
                <h1 v-if="showProducts == true">{{message}}</h1>
            </div>
            <table id="table_container_actual_products">
                <tr>
                    <th>Actual products in making.</th>
                </tr>  
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table id ="table_actual_products" v-for="i in listCurrentproducts">
                            <caption> {{i.room}}</caption>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>
                                    Name:
                                    {{i.name}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>    
                                <td>
                                    LOT:
                                    {{i.lot}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>    
                            <tr>    
                                <td>
                                    Quantity to be package:
                                    {{i.quantity_to_package}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>    
                                <td>
                                    Quantity of pallets: 
                                    {{i.pallets}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>
                                    Progress:
                                    {{i.progress}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    {{i.finished_pallets}} pallets of {{i.pallets}} pallets
                                    <button @click="addPallet(i.room)">Add Pallet</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr v-if="i.pallets == i.finished_pallets">
                                <td>
                                    <h3>Completed</h3>
                                    <button @click="finish(i.room)">Finish procedure</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>    
                </tr> 
            </table>
        </section>
```

el css:

```
.see_actual_products_section{
margin-top: 150px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;}

#table_container_actual_products {
border: 5px solid red; 
}

#table_container_actual_product, th{
border-bottom: 5px solid red; 
}

#table_actual_products {
border: 5px solid black; 
margin:50px;
display: inline-block;
}

#table_actual_products td {
border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

estoy usando display: inline block, que si funciona pero a la hora de que so mas se desordena, gracias :)

Answer (score 2):

Si bien ya te comentaron una respuesta, me gustaría hacer las siguientes observaciones:

**Si te decidieras a seguir con el uso de *Flexbox* entonces** podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Al elemento padre o contenedor de tus cards le pudieras aplicar estas propiedades y valores:

Código:

```
.contenedor {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

La propiedad `flex-wrap` con un valor de `wrap` logrará que cuando los elementos no puedan quedar en la misma fila, entonces se muevan al renglón inmediato.

Para el espacio entre los elementos y lograr que se vea con una distribución uniforme sobre el *main axis* podemos hacer uso de: **`justify-content`** con un valor de: **`space-between`**

**Ahora bien si te decidieras por un sistema de rejillas** pudieras hacer esto:

- Al elemento contenedor, le indicamos que distribuya el contenido en columnas de igual tamaño
- Para evitar caer en el uso de `margin` para el espaciado entre ellas, *CSS Grid* nos ofrece una propiedad llamada **`grid-gap`** con la cual podemos indicar la separación deseada.

Quedando así:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr); 
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
.element {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

- La ventaja de usar: `repeat()` es que esta función nos permitirá indicar cuantas columnas y de que tamaño deben ser.

Con una salida así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

```css
.contenedor-card {
 display:inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  padding:30px;
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.card {
margin: 10px;
width:330px;
height:200px;
background:red;
margin:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class='contenedor-card'>
<div class='card card-1'></div>
<div class='card card-1'></div>
<div class='card card-1'></div>
<div class='card card-1'></div>
<div class='card card-1'></div>
<div class='card card-1'></div>
<div class='card card-1'></div>
<div class='card card-1'></div>
<div class='card card-1'></div>
<div class='card card-1'></div>
<div class='card card-1'></div>
<div class='card card-1'></div>
<div class='card card-1'></div>
<div class='card card-1'></div>
</div>
```

agregando display:inline-grid a tu class: see_actual_products_section y agregando un padding de 30px; (esto lo puedes manejar a tu gusto)y los item les puedes poner un margin: 50px (a tu gusto igual)

Answer (score 0):

Ese problema yo lo solucionaría con divs y floats de esta manera

CSS

```
        .contenedor { border:1px solid #FF0000; }
        .contenedor_titulo { border-bottom:1px solid #FF0000; text-align:center; }
        .contenedor_espacio { clear:both; }
        .producto { float:left; display:block; width:200px; margin:10px; padding:5px; border: 1px solid #009900 }
        .contenedor_cierre { clear:both }
```

HTML

```
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="contenedor_titulo"> tabla título </div>
        <div class="contenedor_espacio"> 
            <div class="producto"> 
                <div> Name: Nombre </div>
                <div> LOT: 12345 </div>
                <div> Development: 50% </div>
            </div>
            <div class="producto"> 
                <div> Name: Nombre </div>
                <div> LOT: 12345 </div>
                <div> Development: 50% </div>
            </div>
            <div class="producto"> 
                <div> Name: Nombre </div>
                <div> LOT: 12345 </div>
                <div> Development: 50% </div>
            </div>
            <div class="producto"> 
                <div> Name: Nombre </div>
                <div> LOT: 12345 </div>
                <div> Development: 50% </div>
            </div>
            <div class="producto"> 
                <div> Name: Nombre </div>
                <div> LOT: 12345 </div>
                <div> Development: 50% </div>
            </div>
            <div class="contenedor_cierre"> </div>
        </div>
    <div>
```

Y la imagen final sería algo como:
[image: Página de ejemplo]